# Probability of a train and a bus will meet

Tags: probability

Would you explain the answer of the question in terms of independent events or other basic concepts in probability?

(Q) A train and a bus arrive at the station at random between 9 am and 10 am. The train stops for 10 minutes and the bus for x minutes. Find x so that the probability that the bus and the train will meet equals 0.5.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: The way to handle such problems is to at first forget the $0.5$ part, and just assume that $x$ is some fixed, but unknown number of minutes. Work out the probability that they will meet up, that will most likely give you a formula containing $x$. Set the formula on one side of an equals sign, and $0.5$ on the other, and solve like any other equation. Your $x$ will be decided as you solve it.

Comment: If there were no such thing as StackExchange, here is what you might do. Try doing a warm-up problem first. Suppose it is known that the bus waits for 3 minutes, and compute the probability that the two will meet. If you understand the "forwards" problem, it can help you do the "inverse" problem posed.

Comment: This is conceptually a simple problem, but the details get rather messy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let the bus arrive at $B$ minutes after $9$ am, let the tram arrive
at $T$ minutes after $9$ am.

Then the event $\left\{ T-10\leq B<T\right\} \cup\left\{ B-x<T\leq B\right\} $
stands for a 'meeting'. This is a union of two disjoint sets and to
be calculated is $P\left\{ T-10\leq B<T\right\} +P\left\{ B-x<T\leq B\right\} $.
This on base of a uniform distribution for $\left(B,V\right)$ on
$\left[0,60\right]^{2}$.

This comes to calculation of $\frac{1}{3600}\int_{0}^{60}\int_{0}^{60}\left[t-10\leq b<t\right]dbdt+\frac{1}{3600}\int_{0}^{60}\int_{0}^{60}\left[b-x\leq t<b\right]dbdt$
where $\left[t-10\leq b<t\right]=1$ if $t-10\leq b<t$ and $\left[t-10\leq b<t\right]=0$
otherwise and likewise for function$\left[b-x\leq t<b\right]$ . This
results in an expression $u\left(x\right)$ in $x$. To be solved
is the equation $u\left(x\right)=0.5$.

Can you take it from here?

**addendum**:

To put some light on the mentioned integrals:

$\int_{0}^{60}\int_{0}^{60}\left[t-10\leq b<t\right]dbdt=\int_{0}^{10}\int_{0}^{t}dbdt+\int_{10}^{60}\int_{t-10}^{t}dbdt$

If $x\leq 60$ then:

$\int_{0}^{60}\int_{0}^{60}\left[b-x\leq t<b\right]dtdb=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{b}dtdb+\int_{x}^{60}\int_{b-x}^{b}dtdb$

And if $x>60$ then:

$\int_{0}^{60}\int_{0}^{60}\left[b-x\leq t<b\right]dtdb=\int_{0}^{60}\int_{0}^{b}dtdb$

Comment: Those integrals look just as complicated as the original problem.

Comment: I was about to post basically this solution, noting however that you can do the integral by graphing the inequalities and computing areas with basic geometry.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, drawing a graph is the way to go.

Comment: (Or in other words, one can do it without the calculus notation.)

Comment: @TonyK My intention is an answer on the question: 'How to solve that?' This with basic concepts in probability. It provides the OP a way to go. If he knows how to handle integrals of characteristic functions then he can do it.

Comment: @JasonZimba If the integrand is a characteristic function then calculating the integral is indeed the same thing as computing an area.

Answer (score -1):

For any time the train arrives, the bus will meet it if it arrives between x minutes before the train arrives and 10 minutes after that.  That is a window of opportunity of $10+x$ minutes in the $60$ minute frame.  Find the $x$ that gives the required probability.

Comment: No, it's complicated by the edge effects. If the train arrives before 9am + x minutes, or after 9:50, the window is smaller.